# Showing these are the only functions in "Find All"

Tags: functions, proof-writing, solution-verification, contest-math, functional-equations

This question is not particularly difficult, in terms of finding the answers. I want to make sure the **"proof"** is complete, in particular the part of "find all" questions where you need to show that these are the only functions that satisfy.

> *(High School Contest Math-Subjective) Find all linear functions $f: \mathfrak{R} \rightarrow \mathfrak{R}$ such that $f(x)=4f^{-1}(x)+27$*

**I can find the functions:**

Substitute $f(x)=ax+b\implies f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-b}{a}$ in the given condition:

$$ax+b=4(\frac{x-b}{a})+27=\frac{4x-4b+27a}{a}$$
Cross-multiply in the first and last equality:
$$a^2x+ab=4x-4b+27a$$

Equating coefficients:
$$x \text{ term: } a^2=4⇒a=±2$$
$$\text{Constant Term: }ab=27a-4b$$
$$\text{Case I}: a=2⇒2b=54-4b⇒6b=54⇒b=9⇒f_1 (x)=2x+9$$
$$\text{Case II}: a=-2⇒-2b=-54-4b⇒2b=-54⇒b=-27⇒ f_2 (x)=-2x-27$$

**I need to demonstrate that these are the only functions that satisfy the given functional equation.**

Is it sufficient to say that since I have chosen the most general form of a linear function, and substituted into the equation, I have found all the solutions?
Or is anything further needed?

Comment: Nothing more to be done. You have already found  all linear functions satisfying the given equation.

Comment: "Find All" questions require not just the finding, but also showing that no other solutions are possible. That is the part I am asking about.

Comment: It says 'find all **linear** functions....'. All linear functions are of the form $f(x)=ax+b$.

Comment: can you write up an answer to that effect. I am quite happy if my proof doesn't need any changes. then I can accept it.

Comment: You have shown correctly that if $f(x)=ax+b$ is a linear solution then $(a,b)=(2,9)$ or $(a,b)=(-2,-27)$ but you did not show that if $(a,b)=(2,9)$ or $(a,b)=(-2,-27)$ then $f(x)=ax+b$ is a solution. This is easily fixed: The reasoning you have stated is of the form $f(x)=ax+b\implies ... \implies [(a,b)=(2,9) \lor (a,b)=(-2,-27)]$ but in all the  steps the $\implies$ can be replaced by $\iff.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks.